# AlpineJS - autoselection doesn't work when there is more than one todo

Tags: alpine.js

I'm making a little todo app in [AlpineJS](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine) and I'm running into a problem of *autoselecting* a field when a user *clicks* on a todo. This problem only happens when there are multiple todos.

When the user enters the first todo onto the app, they can then click on the todo to edit it. The field will *autoselect* as expected. However, when the user adds more than one todo onto the app and wants to edit the *n+1* todo, the field will no longer autoselects,  but the first todo still autoselects just fine.

Here's my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/NeroSonic/pen/jOPGjYj) for your reference.

Here's what my *edit* functionality looks like:

**JS**

```
[...]
edit(todo) {
    todo.editing = !todo.editing
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      document.getElementById(`edit-${todo.id}`).select()
    })
  }
[...]
```

**HTML**

```
[...]
<div
  x-text="todo.item"
  class="todo-item"
  @click="edit(todo)" // <-- point of interest
  x-show="!todo.editing"
  :class="{ 'completed' : todo.completed }"
  >
</div>

<input
  type="text"
  x-show="todo.editing"
  :value="todo.item"
  x-model="todo.item"
  @keydown.enter="edit(todo)"
  @keydown.escape="todo.editing = false"
  @click.away="todo.editing = false"
  class="edit-input"
  :id="`edit-${todo.id}`" // <-- point of interest
/>
[...]
```

Would anyone have an idea of what might be wrong with my logic? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems using `setTimeout(() => { ... }, 1)` (timeout of 1ms) works, see the following [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hugodf/pen/xxwPvKy) modified from yours.

There are known issues in Alpine.js around `$nextTick`.

I would also recommend using `x-ref` instead of `id`s, so your input would look as follows:

```
<input
  type="text"
  x-show="todo.editing"
  :value="todo.item"
  x-model="todo.item"
  @keydown.enter="edit(todo)"
  @keydown.escape="todo.editing = false"
  @click.away="todo.editing = false"
  class="edit-input"
  :x-ref="`edit-${todo.id}`"
/>
```

You can then set `edit(todo)` to be:

```
  edit(todo) {
    todo.editing = !todo.editing
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$refs[`edit-${todo.id}`].select()
    }, 1)
  }
```